# Как проверить есть ли в слове повторяющиеся буквы?

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит слово. Программа должна проверить, есть ли в строке одинаковые буквы и посчитать сколько раз они встречаются.

Использовать массивы, модули, листы и словари нельзя. Только цикл, только строки.

```
word = str(input('Введіть слово: '))
count = 0

while count <= len(word):
   for i in word:
       if i == word.[count]
print(count)
```

Пробовала что-то такое, но результат неверный, подсчитывает только кол-во символов.

Comment: <offtopic>я бы вашего препода за такое задание в колхоз на картошку отправил! Для задачи на циклы можно было придумать гораздо более элегантную задачу. А так студенты начнут думать, что так и надо писать программы ¯\_ಠ_ಠ_/¯ </offtopic>

Comment: вы уверены, что словари использовать нельзя?

Comment: согласна с вами. программа легко решается с помощью массива, а как решить эту я не знаю. запрет на использование словарей и всего остального - это одно из главных условий

Comment: множества `set()` - тоже нельзя использовать?

Comment: множества нельзя :)

Answer (score 4):

Только цикл, только строки:

```
word = "гиппопотам"
seen = ""

for c in word:
    if c not in seen:
        print(f"{c}: {word.count(c)}")
        seen += c
```

вывод:

```
г: 1
и: 1
п: 3
о: 2
т: 1
а: 1
м: 1
```

Comment: большое спасибо, но учитывая, что преподователь довольно требовательный, нужен вариант полегче

Comment: @anastasia, "Не ищите лёгких путей, ищите правильный!" (c) - автора не помню... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Если нельзя ни словарей ни массивов, ни сета, тогда я вижу такой вариант - для первой буквы в слове проверять есть ли у нее повторения, если есть, то вывести сколько их, затем удалить все вхождения этой буквы и продолжать до тех пор пока строка не будет пустой.

```
word = "гиппопотам"

while word:
    if word.count(word[0])>1: # если вывод количества нужен для всех, а не только для повторяющихся, то этот if можно убрать
        print(word[0], ':', word.count(word[0]))
    word = word.replace(word[0], '')
```

Comment: говорю, напишите код пожалуйста)

Comment: добавил код в ответ

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: немного подправил код, упростил вывод

Answer (score 1):

```
word = input('Введіть слово: ')

for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i] not in word[:i]:
        print(word[i], word.count(word[i]))
```

Вот второй вариант:

```
word = input('Введіть слово: ')
 
for i in range(len(word)):
    if i == word.find(word[i]):
        print(word[i], word.count(word[i]))
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь